# Issues on using $.post to insert db data through PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

So... I've been trying to use a JQuery post requests to insert data in my database for 2 days and can't make it work, and don't have any idea why... I bet someone already faced this issue too, so I'm here looking for this person :)

Here's the issue:

Into the html file, the part with JQuery (it's on a click event):

```
var eventData;

eventData = {
  title: title,
  start: start,
  end: end
};

$.post("add.php", eventData);
```

The add.php file:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jqcalendar" );

$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO jqcalendar(title,start,end) VALUES({$title},{$start},{$end})");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Can't make this thing work, already tried putting echoes but it seems the php file isn't even being executed by the $.post command... If someone could help I'd really really appreciate it...

EDIT:
the title, start and end are strings previously defined with the "" !

I used the console inspection and got this error at the same line as the
$.post:

$.fullCalendar.select   @   index.html:35

Comment: Strings need to be quoted in a query, also you might want to consider using a parameterized query, to avoid errors like this and sql injection and what not.

Comment: Check your browser's console. You probably have an error or are using the wrong path to `add.php`. Check the *Network* console for the AJAX `POST` request and inspect the request and response data. Finally, use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to insert values in to your database without introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Do you have a table called `jqcalendar` in your database called `jqcalendar`? If not, I'm guessing one of those needs to be changed.

Comment: Also, make sure you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your development environment's `php.ini`. Try adding this to the top of your `add.php` script to get MySQLi to report all errors ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Does your `add.php` script start with `<?php`?

Comment: my add.php starts with the <?php tag.
look at the EDIT part please people, the issue isn't this

Comment: Did you tried with `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`?

Comment: yea, nothing happened all the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **quotes** when you are specifying the value in a javascript object (otherthan for numbers).

```
eventData = {
  title: "title",
  start: "start",
  end: "end"
};
```

**Tips**

Also, you can see whether there's an error with your javascript part by **inspecting element**. Right click and click inspect/inspect element. Then go to the console. You will see errors there if there's any once you execute the javascript part.

Also when debugging javascript part, you can use `console.log()` to see the values of the variables

Comment: but these are other variables previously defined at the click moment, I'll try the console

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the problem is within the variables "start" and "end", they're composite date type ISO8601, what was causing trouble when received for inserting into database... thank you all for your time, but now the problem is converting this date object to a custom String...